# tableViewer.setInput with monitor

Tags: java, progress-bar, monitor, tableviewer

I have a **Table viewer** with 3 columns and several rows (>4000).

When call `tableviewer.setInput(myList)` it takes forever and i'm ok with that but i wanted to implement a monitor so that the user can know what's going on but i have no idea how to start or where to call the monitor. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using SWT/JFace (you are not saying explicitly, but from the code snippet I guess you do).

Did you think about using SWT.VIRTUAL for you table?

Have a look at [the TableViewer JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TableViewer.html) and the the [ILazyContentProvider JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html).

If you can't or don't want to use virtual tables, there's no easy way I know of to display a progress bar while performing setInput(), because setInput() has to be called from the UI thread and will block until finished. So there's not really a way of updating the UI while waiting for setInput to return (not if you don't implement the viewer and the setInput method yourself, at least)...